# zf2 tablegateway select columns by column name

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

```
<code> 
$resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select ( function ($select) {
$select->columns ( 
        array (
        'id',
        'category_name' 
) );
```

} );

tried with above code but it returning all columns, below is the output of return. I need to select id and category_name from database

`Category\Model\Category Object
(
    [id] => 2
    [category_name] => Cat Two
    [category_created] => 
    [category_status] => 
    [inputFilter:protected] => 
)
Category\Model\Category Object
(
    [id] => 4
    [category_name] => Cat one
    [category_created] => 
    [category_status] => 
    [inputFilter:protected] => 
)`

Comment: What is the Problem? You tell the gateway to only select `id` and `category_name` and the gateway only populates those two fields. So what exactly is your problem, what do you want to do?

Comment: here i want to retrieve only id and category_name but why category status and category_created is coming...

Comment: Because you told your `TableGateway` to return a `Category` Object. Those Category objects however do have NO DATE on all other fields except the ones you want. So I really don't see what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I think it might be because the function is being ignored inside the first select function and it just just returning everything.  I found a way to get this to work, try something like the following:

Use the Select class along with the selectWith function of the tablegateway:

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select as Select;

$select = new Select();
$select->from('table');
$select->columns(array('id','category_name'));

$resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
```