# How to get specific column from Model in zf2

Tags: zend-framework2

I have function in model, in which i retrieve data from database based on id,it display me all data of table. However I want to display only password I means specific column's data, How can I do this?

here is my function.

```
public function getProfile($id)
{
    $id  = (int) $id;
    $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('id' => $id));
    $row1 = $rowset->current(); 
    print_r($row1);
    exit;
}
```

This code display me:

```
Admin\Model\Profile Object ( [id] => 9 [name] => Ayaz1 khan [email] => ayaz1@yahoo.com [password] => 51e232a1579ba7074ba4e2d09c956dcb [inputFilter:protected] => ) .
```

Answer (score 1):

Guess your problem's answer just lies there, simply add a 
`$select->where(array('id' => $id));` on the Select object : [zf2 tablegateway select columns by column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965603/zf2-tablegateway-select-columns-by-column-name/29114618#29114618)

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select as Select;

$select = new Select();
$select->from('tableName');
$select->columns(array('password'));
$select->where(array('id' => $id));

$resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
```